# Can I constantly send network request by updating location when application is entering background?

Tags: ios

I have a application need send user's location information to server.
With setting "Required background modes",It can call didUpdateToLocation.
But I can send network request in didUpdateToLocation and not reject by Apple?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends. If the user completely understands that their data will be sent to your servers (and saved?) it will not be rejected by Apple. But it can't consume tons of battery, it also can't run for more than 24 hours with the user reactivating it. They put that in place so you can't have people use your app to stalk some one.